# Split specific line in text file to x, y variables in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have made a code in python that read text file (Test.text), the text file contains data like in below

```
10 20
15 90
22 89
12 33
```

I can read specific line by use this code

```
  particular_line = linecache.getline('Test.txt', 1)
  print(particular_line)
```

I tried to use code to split the text file to x, y value but it got all lines not the specific line that I need

```
with open('Test.txt') as f:
x,y = [], []
for l in f:
    row = l.split()
    x.append(row[0])
    y.append(row[1])
```

So how to get specific line and split it to two values x and y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might do

```
  particular_line = linecache.getline('Test.txt', 1)
  print(particular_line)
  x, y = particular_line.split()
  print(x)  # 10
  print(y)  # 20
```

`.split()` does give list with 2 elements, I used so called unpacking to get 1st element into variable `x` and 2nd into `y`.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the readlines in your code

```py
with open('Test.txt') as f:
x,y = [], []
for l in f.readlines():
    row = l.split()
    x.append(row[0])
    y.append(row[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

xy = pd.read_csv("Test.txt", sep=" ", header=None).rename(columns={0:"x", 1:"y"})
```

Now you can access to all `x` and `y` values with `xy.x.values` and `xy.y.values`.
Note that I chose `sep=" "` as separator becose I suppose that your x and y are separated by a single space in you file.

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather condensed example:

```py
with open("input.txt", "r") as f:
    data = f.read()

# Puts data into array line by line, then word by word
words = [y.split() for y in data.split("\n")]

# Gets first word (x)
x = [x[0] for x in words]
# Gets second word (y)
y = [x[1] for x in words]
```

Where `[y.split() for y in data.split("\n")]` gets each line by splitting at `\n` and splits the x and y values (`.split()`) by the space in-between them

Comment: Just re-read question, fixing now

Answer (score 0):

To get the specific line you can use this code

```
with open('Test.txt') as f:
    particular_line = f.readlines()[1]
    print(particular_line)
```

Notice the index inside `[]`, it starts from `0` as same as most other languages. For example, if you want to get the first line, you'd change it to `0`.
By parsing it into two variables you can use

```
    x, y = particular_line.split()
    print(x)
    print(y)
```

So, put them together,

```
with open('Test.txt') as f:
    particular_line = f.readlines()[1]
    print(particular_line)
    x, y = particular_line.split()
    print(x)
    print(y)
```

You might also need it in a function format,

```
def get_particular_line_to_x_y(filename, line_number):
    with open(filename) as f:
        particular_line = f.readlines()[line_number]
        return particular_line.split()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x, y = get_particular_line_to_x_y('Test.txt', 0)
    print(x)
    print(y)
```